# c++ multiple finder

Tags: c++

im trying to find multiples of an array using a loop

```
  int array[11] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};

  int size=11;

for(int i=0;i > size;i++)
{
 if (i%2==!0)
cout << array[i];
}
```

why wont this work

Comment: can you be more clear? detailed example please?

Comment: Please get your code right before posting. Adding bogus code like `i---` after answers have been posted is not a good idea. Reverting to original.

Comment: Please consider your actions before posting offensive, rude, ignorant, or hateful speech. These questions are open to the public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Declare num first.

//Correct if condition..

//correct condition checking in for loop

```
int array[11] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
  int index=2;
  int size=11;
int num = 5;

for(int i=0;i < size;i++)
{
 if (i%num==0)
cout << array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to change the (somewhat ... unusual):

```
if (i%2==!0)
```

into:

```
if (i % 2 == 0)
```

In addition, you loop termination condition is such that the loop will never execute. Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
```